# How many times will this magic method ( __set ) be performed ? Why?

Tags: php

```php
class abc{
    function __construct(){
        $this->abc = 123;
    }
    
    function index(){
        $this->abc = 2222;
    }
    
    //How many times will this magic method  be performed ?
    function __set($name,$value){
        $this->$name = $value;
        echo $value;
    }
}

class abc2 extends abc{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        parent::index();
        $this->abc = 3333;
    }
}

$abc2 = new abc2();
echo $abc2->index();
```

Shouldn't it be performed three times?

Comment: What does your debugging tell you?

Comment: 123
It operates normally without error.

Answer (score 1):

it should be performed only 1 time, because magic method `__set` is executed only if variable is not defined, during first call - variable gets defined and thus no more calls should happen

though, if you comment `$this->$name = $value;` part - you will see that `__set` is executed 4 times:

1. abc constructor
2. abc index via abc2 construct
3. abc2 construct
4. abc2 index (which is actually abc index)

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer is very good. I finally know the reason!

Comment: `__set` is also called when trying to write to an inaccessible (protected or private) property. So if `class abc` would have a property `private abc;`, then the __set would be called once in `abc2::__construct`.